# How do you handle errors raised in Python Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, error-handling, paramiko

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    self.ssh.connect(self.hostname, username=self.username, password=self.password)
except SSHException:
    #do something
```

I was wondering how to handle errors raised by Paramiko when trying to connect to an SSH server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your application.

Here are some possible actions:

- Terminate
- Retry
- Log the error and continue doing something else

Comment: I understand this, but I'm having trouble catching the error raised. For example whenever I try to connect to an invalid host, it halts my program and a window pops up saying there's an error. I want to be able to handle that when it happens without halting my program

Comment: Without knowing the actual text of the error message in the popup, we'd just be guessing.